# Is there a way to bind a button on the form to the keyboard arrows?

Tags: c#, user-interface

I am trying to create user controls on a simple number sliding game. Instead of using traditional click interface I wanted to use the keyboard but i cant find anyway to bind specific keys to specific buttons and I don't if it is possible to create a keyboard button press event.

is there a way to code a keyboard button press event into the program?

Comment: What UI technology are you writing your UI in?  I'm thinking either WPF or WinForms from your question?  I'd add that as a tag to your question rather than visual-studio-2013, which is just the IDE you're using to build it in.

Comment: Sorry. Very new to this. Still very new to programming. I'm using WinForms. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There sure is, in the button click event handler just add a call to this API:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.send(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Why is this not an accepted answer? This API works from any .NET program (command line, Winforms or WPF). I've used it in all 3. It's just a wrapper around a P/Invoke call.